# using window.location and window.history

Tags: javascript

If you use gmail, you will notice that once you are logged in, and click the back and forward buttons, the page isn't reloaded, and therefore the navigation is really quick. Doing a little research, I've found out about the window.history and window.location of javascript. It seems that these can be used to achieve the functionality the gmail uses.
I want to use this on our site, since the reloads every time a user clicks the back and forward button.
I have found this doc (window. history):  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history

But I what triggers the history.back() method for instance? I guess these are called when a user clicks on the back button in the browser? But how do you know when the user clicks the back and/or forward button, so that you can take the necessary action in your code?

Should anyone have a nice js fiddle on the use of window.history, it would be appreciated

Comment: They probably use [`window.onhashchange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onhashchange) or, more likely, the [`hashchange` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#event-hashchange).

Answer (score 0):

"The JavaScript History object - property of the window object - contains an array / list of previously visited URLs. In this article, we will look at the history object properties and methods, length, current, next, previous properties, back(), forward() and go() methods along with syntax and examples.

Mostly, JavaScript history object is used to simulate the browser's back button:

href="javascript:history.go(-1)"

Answer (score 0):

The History API doesn't really work in jsFiddle due to the iFrames, so that's really not an option.

The `popstate` event fires when the back button is pushed, from **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popstate)**

> The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as
>   a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript).

You'd use the `pushstate()` and `replaceState()` functions etc. to change the URL without reloading the page, it's all very well [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but it is a little more complicated than regular URL's, and you'll probably need fallbacks for older browsers etc.

[**History.js**](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) is a library for working with the History API, I believe it's no longer being developed, but maybe it can be helpful anyway.